# Converting UTF-8 to UTF-16 in C

Tags: c, character-encoding, utf

I have a word for example "James". I read it from a .dat file. I read it from a UTF-8 file and I want to convert it into UTF-16 format. How can I do that ?

My OS is Linux Debian.

Comment: UTF-16 should be obsoleted (if it hasn't been already).

Comment: If you don't want to use external libraries, maybe this [gist](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiL55fJysnwAhVlCGMBHRoYBmEQFjAAegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.github.com%2Ftommai78101%2F3631ed1f136b78238e85582f08bdc618&usg=AOvVaw10n7xsgHuqIX2e00MuhLxs) can help you. Else have a look at libicu.

Comment: @Programmer Can we directly read a .dat file in UTF-16 format. Not opening it in UTF-16 format just want to read a single line for example.

Comment: When you read in binary format, you are responsible to interpret the data.

Comment: "Not opening it in UTF-16 format just want to read a single line" - You can read a line from the UTF-8 encoded file, then convert it to UTF-16 in memory, with the gist I linked or with a third party library like libicu.

Comment: You could use the `iconv_open()`, `iconv()` and `iconv_close()` functions (run the `iconv -l` shell command for a list of possible charsets to convert between. Alternatively, you could call `setlocale()` setting a UTF-8 locale, and use the C library `mbrtoc16` function to convert multibyte character sequences to UTF-16 character sequences.

Comment: In memory, you don't have to worry much about big-endian vs little-endian.  When writing to disk, or over the network, you do have to worry about UTF-16BE vs UTF-16LE, possibly by including a BOM (byte-order mark) at the start of the output.  And generally, there's little point in using UTF-16 unless you're planning to write the data to a file or over the network — you'd be better off with UTF-32 since you then have one unit of 4 bytes of data for each Unicode code point, whereas with UTF-16 you sometimes need one unit of 2 bytes and sometimes two units of 2 bytes for a single code point.

Comment: If you're going to do the conversion yourself, it will probably be easiest to write a UTF-8 to UTF-32 converter, and a UTF-32 to UTF-16 converter, rather than one that converts direct from UTF-8 to UTF-16.

Comment: @pmg That is rather moot as there is a lot of UTF-16 data in the wild, code that relies on UTF-16, etc.